# Form with in Form submit request twice by Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, request, form-submit

I have a Form which contains another form.
When I'm submitting the nested form through javascript, It is submitting twice in Internet Explorer, but only one in any other browser.
How to submit the nested form to send only one request in IE.

#### Edit:

I'm using onchange event to submit the nested form.. so how the click can work in my case?

Comment: "I have a Form which contains another form." — You have invalid HTML. Fix it. Then worry about whatever problem you are having.

Comment: @Quentin i have a form in one page and another form in another page, the second form is a piece in first page.. Using Tiles...

Comment: What's a tile? You still can't have a form element that is a descendant of another form element.

Comment: @Quentin Using Tiles concept, Means multiple pages are formed as a single page to the end user,the feel..

Comment: If you are combining multiple files into a single page, then it is your responsibility to make sure that the results are valid. Nested forms are not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't be nesting forms, but you can stop the propagation of the event. For instance, if your `click` event is submitting the outside form, do the following:

```
$("form").on("click", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Be sure to read [the notes regarding event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/#notes-0).

Also, it's not necessary to nest forms. You can have a submit button within one form submit an entirely different form if you like; just use the `form` attribute on the button itself:

```
<form id="foo">
    <!-- Within #foo, but I submit #bar -->
    <input type="submit" form="bar" value="Within Foo" />
</form>

<form id="bar">
    <!-- Within #bar, but I submit #foo -->
    <input type="submit" form="foo" value="Within Bar" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I should note that the `form` attribute isn't supported like this in Internet Explorer 10. You could patch this logic though with some simple logic like this:

```
$(":submit[form]").on("click", function ( e ) {
    $( "#" + $(this).attr("form") ).submit();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This will stop the problem, but you really shouldn't have a form inside a form...

Comment: @Dameo I'm aware of that. Not knowing the user's setup or restrains, I find it helpful to answer their question, and then voice concerns (and solutions) afterwards.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I'm using onchange event to submit the nested form.. so how the click can work in my case?

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary Change the code so that `onchange` doesn't propagate then.

Comment: @JonathanSampson In place of "click" i have to replace "change" in the   solution what you have provided..? I'm new bee to jquery working...

Comment: @JonathanSampson I didn't mean to seem as if I was criticizing, was just adding that in as well.  Lazily phrased sentence.

Comment: @Dameo Wasn't taken the wrong way; thank you for contributing to the response. Your input is valuable.